# How do I get a site's WordPress template from its host?

Tags: wordpress

I have access to a site host and I want to get its WordPress template, how can I do this to install the template on my site as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to any wordpress website as administrator, you can install [WP Theme Plugin Download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-theme-plugin-download/) plugin and on the themes or plugins list, you can download a theme or plugin easily.

This plugin is very helpful if you don't have access to hosting account of the website. Or you don't want to install a File Manager plugin to get access to certain files or folders. This plugin simply zips the theme or plugin folder and lets you download it with a single click.

If you have only access to its hosting account, then simply use file manager of the control panel and navigate to `/wp-content/themes` zip the folder of the theme and download.